# getting a specific pattern of result after looping the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

A dump question:

```
var arr = ['top', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3' .. goes];
```

How can I get a result like below after looping this array?

> result_string => #top, #top/dir1, #top/dir1/dir2, #top/dir1/dir2/dir3

btw is there a problem having a slash for jQuery selectors,

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
var arr = ['top','dir1','dir2','dir3'];

for(var i=0,j=arr.length;i<j;i++)
{
   arr[i] = i  > 0 ? arr[i-1] + '/' + arr[i] : '#'+arr[i];
}

alert(arr.join(','))
```

Comment: And your second question,i just tested,and found jquery can not get the element object when i add slash to id string,so you'd better keep your html element's id be a valid string for jquery.

Comment: Is `j` really required in the for loop? Can't it be `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`?

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) means you calculate arr's length each loop,so i think that should be ignore..:-)

Comment: @Lake I checked the link James referred and I was able to use slashes when you escape with 2 backslashes so the line became like this:  arr[i] = i  > 0 ? arr[i-1] + '\\/' + arr[i] : '#'+arr[i];

Comment: @neverlate yes you're right and thank James's link, glad to know this.:-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet for you:

```
var arr = ['top', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3'];
var result_string = "";
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var requiredVal = "#";
    for(j = 0; j <=i; j++) {
        requiredVal += arr[j];
        requiredVal += j==i ? "" : "/";
    }
    result_string += requiredVal;
    result_string += i+1 < arr.length ? ", " : "";
}
alert(result_string);
```

You can escape and use `/` character. See the reference: [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: FYI: reference says use 2 back slashes to escape a slash for jQuery selectors